# Is it recommended to create a new user?

Tags: 16.04, server, lamp

I am installing LampServer and I have no problem with the installation process, as I have installed before, but I have some doubts.

I'm reading about installing LampServer on a site called DigitalOcean, and in the "Prerequisites" I saw that I must have a non-root account, and this is where my question arises: I did not create any user except during installation. By the terminal, with the command "whoami", I see that I am using the user that I created during the installation, should I create a new user or not?

I hope that I am clear in this.

If you want to visit the site: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant section from the article:

> Before you begin with this guide, you should have a separate, non-root user account with sudo privileges set up on your server.

Here, "non-root" means *not the `root` user*; so, any user who is not `root` with sufficient privilege to impersonate `root` using `sudo` will do -- like the user you created during installation.

So, you don't have to create a new user, your current one is sufficient for this purpose.